# How to determine whether the user has switched to another tab of the current browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to determine using jquery or javascript that is the user has switched tab standing on the same browser?

I.e. if the user is currently standing on browser say mozilla-firefox tab no.1 , now he has opened another tab say tab no.2 , at that point a popup should appear , with the message "tab changed"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this might work, but will popup when the user leaves th esite in anyway not just tab changes

```
window.onunload = popup;

function popup() {
  alert('tab changed');
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I believe you can use the `window.onblur` [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onblur) which will fire when the current page loses focus.

```
window.onblur = function() {
    // Your action here
};
```

In jQuery, you write it this way

```
$(window).blur(function() {
    // Your action here
});
```

Comment: This will also trigger when you focus the inspect side bar which can cause strange behaviour.

Comment: @anonymous-dev this answer is from over a decade ago, and has been closed for more than half of that time. A better solution is to use the Page Visibility API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

Answer (score 7):

Without jQuery

```js
window.onblur = function () {
    // do some stuff after tab was changed e.g.
    alert('You switched the tab');
}
```

with jQuery:

```js
$('window').blur(function () {
    // do some stuff after tab was changed e.g.
    alert('You switched the tab');
});
```

Of course displaying alert is not best thing to do, because it focus current tab again :)

Comment: This will also trigger when you focus the inspect side bar which can cause strange behaviour.